# How do I remove the error that the method must be declared before use in xCode

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am sure I can turn that error off somewhere! Take a look at the following code which throws this error:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NSString *databaseName = @"TasksDB.db";

    NSArray *documentsDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [documentsDir objectAtIndex:0];

    databasePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}


-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase 
{

}
```

The error is thrown that checkAndCreateDatabase is not recognized. This is also because I have not declared the checkAndCreate... method in the interface file and I don't want to.

Comment: I don't want this method to be called from outside and that is why I am not declaring them in my header file. Also asking the question will increase my knowledge of how to turn those errors off :)

Comment: it will only call if you tell it to, so it won't magically be run by some outside force just because it's in the header file.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 I dont want the *some outside force* even seeing these methods. Anyway.. problem solved! (One of the principles of designing a reusable library is that you only expose the methods you want the caller to call). Class Extensions is one way to solve this issue. Another is not declaring them in header file.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the setting: Treat Missing Function Prototypes as Errors. On Xcode 4.4 it is under Apple LLVM compiler 4.0 Warnings All Languages. or -Werror-implicit-function-declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it as a private method in the `.m` file:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

- (void)checkAndCreateDatabase;

@end

@interface AppDelegate

...
```

Comment: Although my question was different I will accept this answer. I know there is a property in build settings somewhere which will allow me to use the methods without using extensions or declaring them in the header files.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be declared in the include and source files as a private method?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class extension at the beginning of your .m file and declare it there.  That keeps it out of the published interface.

(Class extensions are essentially empty categories but with special rules for storage declarations: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html)